# SQL for how to Get next stations based on station_id in GTFS data

Tags: sql, sqlite, gtfs

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
Routes.route_id, Routes.route_desc, Routes.route_type, 
Trips.service_id, Trips.trip_id, Trips.route_direction, 
Stop_times.stop_id, Stop_times.arrival_time, Stop_times.departure_time, 
Stops.stop_name, Calendar.start_date, Calendar.end_date
FROM Trips 
INNER JOIN Routes ON Trips.route_id = Routes.route_id
INNER JOIN Stop_times ON Trips.trip_id = Stop_times.trip_id 
INNER JOIN Stops ON Stop_times.stop_id = Stops.stop_id
INNER JOIN Calendar ON Trips.service_id = Calendar.service_id
WHERE 
Calendar.start_date = strftime('%Y%m%d','now') and
CAST(REPLACE(Stop_times.arrival_time, ':', '') as decimal)  
         >= strftime('%H%M%S', 'now', 'localtime')
and Trips.direction_id = 0
and Stop_times.stop_id = '279018' 
ORDER BY Stop_times.arrival_time asc
```

1> I have resulted as like this

[image]

(many other columns as well)

2>I want to use the first-row trip_id and put that as

```
SELECT 
Routes.route_id, Routes.route_desc, Routes.route_type, 
Trips.service_id, Trips.trip_id, Trips.route_direction, 
Stop_times.stop_id, Stop_times.arrival_time, Stop_times.departure_time, 
Stops.stop_name, Calendar.start_date, Calendar.end_date
FROM Trips 
INNER JOIN Routes ON Trips.route_id = Routes.route_id
INNER JOIN Stop_times ON Trips.trip_id = Stop_times.trip_id 
INNER JOIN Stops ON Stop_times.stop_id = Stops.stop_id
INNER JOIN Calendar ON Trips.service_id = Calendar.service_id
WHERE 
Calendar.start_date = strftime('%Y%m%d','now') and
CAST(REPLACE(Stop_times.arrival_time, ':', '') as decimal)  
         >= strftime('%H%M%S', 'now', 'localtime')
and Trips.direction_id = 0
and Stop_times.trip_id = 'what ever on first row from above query example 551.22018xxxxx' 
ORDER BY Stop_times.arrival_time asc
```

The result should be as following

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What rdbms you are using?

Comment: How about a subquery?

Comment: I don't understand what results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery` to wrap your result and use the result to execute your filter.

Your query should be like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT 
    Routes.route_id, Routes.route_desc, Routes.route_type, 
    Trips.service_id, Trips.trip_id, Trips.route_direction, 
    Stop_times.stop_id, Stop_times.arrival_time, Stop_times.departure_time, 
    Stops.stop_name, Calendar.start_date, Calendar.end_date
 FROM Trips 
    INNER JOIN Routes ON Trips.route_id = Routes.route_id
    INNER JOIN Stop_times ON Trips.trip_id = Stop_times.trip_id 
    INNER JOIN Stops ON Stop_times.stop_id = Stops.stop_id
    INNER JOIN Calendar ON Trips.service_id = Calendar.service_id
 WHERE 
    Calendar.start_date = strftime('%Y%m%d','now') and
    CAST(REPLACE(Stop_times.arrival_time, ':', '') as decimal)  
             >= strftime('%H%M%S', 'now', 'localtime')
    and Trips.direction_id ={}
    and Stops_Time.Stop_ID = 'xxxx' 
ORDER BY Stop_times.arrival_time ASC)
WHERE Trip_ID = @Trip_ID
```

EDIT :

You need just 1 row the first in the `Stop_Times.Stop_ID` so wrap the same condition with your select first and add `limit`

```
 SELECT 
    Routes.route_id, Routes.route_desc, Routes.route_type, 
    Trips.service_id, Trips.trip_id, Trips.route_direction, 
    Stop_times.stop_id, Stop_times.arrival_time, Stop_times.departure_time, 
    Stops.stop_name, Calendar.start_date, Calendar.end_date
 FROM Trips 
    INNER JOIN Routes ON Trips.route_id = Routes.route_id
    INNER JOIN Stop_times ON Trips.trip_id = Stop_times.trip_id 
    INNER JOIN Stops ON Stop_times.stop_id = Stops.stop_id
    INNER JOIN Calendar ON Trips.service_id = Calendar.service_id
 WHERE 
    Calendar.start_date = strftime('%Y%m%d','now') and
    CAST(REPLACE(Stop_times.arrival_time, ':', '') as decimal)  
             >= strftime('%H%M%S', 'now', 'localtime')
    and Trips.direction_id ={}
    and Stop_Times.Trip_ID = 
        (SELECT Stop_Times.Trip_ID
         FROM Trips
            INNER JOIN Stop_times ON Trips.trip_id = Stop_times.trip_id 
            INNER JOIN Stops ON Stop_times.stop_id = Stops.stop_id
            INNER JOIN Calendar ON Trips.service_id = Calendar.service_id
          WHERE
            Calendar.start_date = strftime('%Y%m%d','now') and
            CAST(REPLACE(Stop_times.arrival_time, ':', '') as decimal)  
                   >= strftime('%H%M%S', 'now', 'localtime')
            and Trips.direction_id ={}
          ORDER BY Stop_times.arrival_time ASC LIMIT 1) 
 ORDER BY Stop_times.arrival_time ASC
```

Comment: Thanks  dwir182 
what is got after inner query result is as following
route_id trip_id stop_id
4T.C.551 551.221018.31.1910 279018
4T.C.565 565.221018.31.2019 279018
4T.C.569 569.221018.13.1530 279018
4T.C.571 571.221018.31.1720 279018
with other columns 
but I want to use the first 0 index trip_id and use that trip_id for above query

Comment: I am sorry.. What do you mean? Is it my answer, answering your question?

Comment: What I am trying to do. 
1> want to get data based on stop_id 
2> get trip_id from that result on 0 index 
3> want to use same query result just change is filter by trip_id which i got inby last result on 0 index and now use trip_id instead of stop_id

Comment: I don't understand.. Update your question with your table and sample data and give expected result.. And give more info about that in your question

Comment: Thank you so much 
dwir182  Great 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Gladly to help you @hardika :)